# Would this sensor get damaged without a relay?

Tags: sensor

I'm just learning and looked at this circuit to implement. I have read the infrared sensor could be damaged by the larger current requirement of the light/siren without a relay. Is that true?

If so, why doesn't the light/siren just not operate right due to the sensor only outputting 100 mA vs the need to have 300 mA to operate?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you exceed the sensor's current specification limit for an extended time, it will heat up and eventually fail.

You can boost the siren current by using a transistor buffer. For example, a [2N2222](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf) is good for about 600mA.

Such a setup would look like this ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAXEXG8YlbggFh%20UcFGiEaGMHlyzIdYmAEwMNYpFzYEYbFkhlhcEABMGAMwCGAVwA2HNgHNBAtHlcgUKXlUhsAd08wDEJgml82WQgdYRVw3248PGg6PGJ0tFkaFHowExU-VIkaNgAlYPjYkDw-MRoqeLqYBDYAJ25FPjcEMJFVZDhOcFDwCK8fMcSWECYW7H4UBGwaBF6EPAwCWZhCDZowHPyRGkIUPUGzS1sHQIneMEIqbwfRfyDq1jdJr6g7l-A8QBKg8-g6hweowh9zElHgzimMOhPmad2h6PGITC-gAzoj0VDxnVrHYcQw2AAjQECWpebAeIiRAAeyA8hAZKxAMlo4AEAHkAA4cACWAGMrHYADo4skAOxxAHs2tKABQAWwV5jsAEo2Cz9MIMrRuVkeUCAHLebzSpXSnHCtXCuxWNr-XrdJFvNhAA)):

[image]

You could also use the sensor to activate a relay, assuming the relay coil current is low enough.

Comment: I've got a lot to learn. Thanks for answer, in which I will study.  Though I still don't understand how the sirens 300 ma rating  will overheat the sensor. How can it draw more through the sensor that what the sensor allows?

Comment: In layman's eyes, is the source having the ability to deliver more current, cause the sensor to try and hold back by design,  what the siren is calling for.  In other words  300ma source  to 100ma sensor to 300ma siren?

Comment: Like any transistor, the sensor has some current handling capability based on both its internal 'on' resistance and how well it can dissipate heat. It isn't inherently current-limited. If you pull more current than it is rated for, it will be dissipating more heat than it can get rid of. Thus, it will heat up and fail.

Comment: In contrast, the 2N2222 can sink 600mA continuously. It has both a lower internal 'on' resistance and better thermal performance than the sensor, so it can safely handle 300mA of current.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence with me.  One last question,  I believe I understand it except for the principle of how the  higher load of the siren, causes the sensor to overheat. Do i understand you to say that  there is less resistance in the higher load siren, therefore the flow of current is actually being pulled faster through the sensor than say if it had a 50ma load? And that increased flow/pressure cannot be dissipated  as well by the rated transistor  in the sensor?  Just trying to understand the underlying principle of what I hear is circuit draw.